# Error Activating SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing

I am failing to enable the Publishing Infrastructure feature on SharePoint Online.  I am getting the following error:

> Sorry, something went wrong 
>   A duplicate field name "PublishedLinksDisplayName" was found. 
>   Technical Details
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 
>   Correlation ID: 7255fa9c-0008-1000-cd28-117709c7ac79 
>   Date and Time: 07/04/2015 02:16:04

Comment: Have you tried activating it before, and if so - did it create a library you need to manually delete now?

Comment: This was my first time activating the feature. I tried to disable it so that I could re-enable it but it said that the feature was not activated. I need to unhide the "PublishedLinksDisplayName" column and delete it but I can't find a command that I can use to do that.

Comment: Is the id same or we need to find the id?

Answer (score -1):

Deactivate the feature and then try to reactivate it. It might solve the problem

**To Deactivate**

```
stsadm -o deactivatefeature -id f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa -url "<Site Collection URL>" -force
```

**To Activate**

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -id f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa -url "<Site Collection URL>" -force
```